# ValueError: no tables found

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Okay, should be an easy one for some of you, but I could not find any solution to this problem of mine. I'm trying to scrape a table from NHL.com, but it won't find any – I've tried 'table', 'ReactTable', anything.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
```

```
url = "http://www.nhl.com/stats/teams?report=goalsbyperiod&reportType=game&dateFrom=2020-03-11&dateTo=2020-09-11&gameType=3&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=period1GoalsFor&page=0&pageSize=50"
response = requests.get(url)
```

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

```
result = soup.find_all('table')
df_raw = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

It only says ValueError: no tables found

The same code works in most of the websites I use. Please, help.

Comment: The page has javascript which loads the data after the page is displayed... You need to start with a browser instance that runs the JS, then scrap data!

Answer (score 1):

The data on page is inside `div` not `table`. You can use `selenium` for this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time

chrome_driver = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/chromedriver'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver)
url = 'http://www.nhl.com/stats/teams?report=goalsbyperiod&reportType=game&dateFrom=2020-03-11&dateTo=2020-09-11&gameType=3&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=period1GoalsFor&page=0&pageSize=50'

browser.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

data = browser.find_element_by_class_name('rt-tbody').text
```

**Output:**

```
1
Colorado Avalanche
15
9
5
--
--
```