# Python Scrap Same item from all subpages using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrap "salary" from each subpage. For one of the subpage, I am copying the specific contents of the `soup =BeautifulSoup(requests.get('url_of_job').text`. I copied `soup` content to a word file and sliced the content surrounding `salary` and copied here. Copying all  text crosses the limit here.

soup =

````
```
        </style>
<script type="application/ld+json">
        {
            "@context"          :   "https://schema.org",
            "@type"             :   "Organization",
            "url"               :   "https://www.higheredjobs.com",
            "logo"              :   "https://www.higheredjobs.com/assets/hej/img/HEJ_Logo_2c.png",
            "potentialAction"   :   {
                                        "@type"         : "SearchAction",
                                        "target"        : "https://www.higheredjobs.com/search/advance_action.cfm?Keyword={Keyword}",
                                        "query-input"   : "required name=Keyword"
                                    }
        }
        </script>
<script type="application/ld+json">
                    {
                        "@context"              :   "http://schema.org/",
                        "@type"                 :   "JobPosting",
                        "industry"              :   ["Academic/Education","Education"],
                        "title"                 :   "Assistant Professor of Engineering F99507",
                        "description"           :   "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;u&gt;MCNEESE STATE UNIVERSITY&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;strong&gt; invites applicants for the position of Assistant Professor of Engineering.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DEPARTMENT: &lt;/strong&gt;Engineering and Computer Science&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;POSITION INFORMATION: &lt;/strong&gt;This is a full-time, 9-month, unclassified, tenure-track position. The appointment begins in January 2023.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;POSITION NUMBER: &lt;/strong&gt;F99507&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;SALARY: &lt;/strong&gt;$76,000&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;REPORTING AUTHORITY: &lt;/strong&gt;Department Head of Engineering and Computer Science&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;POSITION DUTIES/RESPONSIBILITIES: &lt;/strong&gt;The Assistant Professor of Engineering is responsible for functions related to teaching courses, advising students, and conducting research. The assistant professor will work closely with faculty and staff in the Department of Engineering and Computer Science.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;REQUIRED/PREFERRED QUALIFICATIONS: &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;Required&lt;/u&gt;:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Master of Engineering with 18 hours in Electrical Engineering&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Experience with Power Engineering&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;Preferred&lt;/u&gt;:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;PhD in Electrical Engineering&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DEADLINE: &lt;/strong&gt;Position will remain open until filled.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;APPLICATION PROCESS AND MATERIALS: &lt;/strong&gt;For the application process, applicants are required and &lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;MUST&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; complete an electronic application and upload required documents listed below:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Letter of Application (Cover Letter)&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Resume/Vitae&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Three Professional References (include: name, phone number, and e-mail address)&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Unofficial Transcripts&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;TO APPLY FOR THIS VACANCY, &lt;/strong&gt;click on the &lt;strong&gt;&amp;ldquo;APPLY&amp;rdquo;&lt;/strong&gt; button at the top of advertisement to complete the electronic application, which can be used for this vacancy as well as future job opportunities. Applicants are responsible for checking the status of their application to determine where they are in the recruitment process. Further status message information is located under the Information section of the Current Job Opportunities page.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;ALL JOB OFFERS ARE CONTINGENT UPON THE SUCCESSFUL RESULT OF A CRIMINAL BACKGROUND CHECK AND RECEIPT OF TRANSCRIPT(S) IF APPLICABLE.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;If you have questions regarding this recruitment, please contact the HR Liaison:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Kim Dronett at &lt;a rel=&quot;noopener&quot; href=&quot;kdronett@mcneese.edu&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;kdronett@mcneese.edu&lt;/a&gt; or (337) 475-5413.&lt;/p&gt;",
                        "datePosted"            :   "2022-09-02 09:48:23.527",

                    
                    
                        "validThrough"          :   "2023-03-01 23:59:59.9",
                    
                        "baseSalary"            :   {
                                                    "@type"         :   "MonetaryAmount",
                                                    "currency"      :   "USD",
                                                    "value"         :   {
                                                                                "@type"     :   "QuantitativeValue",
                                                                            
                                                                                "value" :   "76,000.00",
                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                "unitText"  :   "YEAR"
                                                                            }
                                                    },
                                
                        "hiringOrganization"    :   {
                                                        "@type"     :   "Organization",
                                                        
                                                            "id"        :   "http://www.mcneese.edu",
                                                            "url"       :   "http://www.mcneese.edu",
                                                                                                            
                                                        "name"      :   "McNeese State University"
                                                    },
                        "jobLocation"           :   {
                                                        "@type"     :   "Place",
                                                        "address"   :   {
                                                                            "@type"             :   "PostalAddress",
                                                                            "addressLocality"   :   "Lake Charles",
                                                                            "addressRegion"     :   "LA",
                                                                            "addressCountry"    :   "US"
                                                                        }
                                                    },
                    

                        "employmentType"        :   "FULL_TIME",
                        "image"                 :   "https://www.higheredjobs.com/assets/hej/img/HEJ_Logo_2c.png"
                    }
                </script>
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
                @media (min-width: 768px) { /*menus work different at XS*/
                    HEADER ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > .arrow,
                    HEADER ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            </style>
</noscript>

<div class="col-6">
<h5>Resources</h5>
<ul>
<li><a href="/career/">Career Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="/salary/">Salary Data</a></li>
<li><a href="/career/resumes.cfm">Job Search Tips</a></li>
<li><a href="/career/ResumeService.cfm">Resume/CV Writing<br/> Service</a></li>
<li><a href="/articles/DiversityResources.cfm">Diversity Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="/career/SiteListings.cfm">Search Firms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown js-emplogin">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/employers/">


<div class="" id="jobAttrib">
<div class="job-info">
<strong>Type:</strong>
        Full-Time
        <br/>
<strong>Salary:</strong>
            $76,000.00 USD Per Year
            <br/>
<strong>Posted:</strong>
            09/02/2022 
            <br/>
<strong>Application Due:</strong>
            Open Until Filled
            <br/>
<strong>Category:</strong>
<a class="job-cat" href="/faculty/search.cfm?JobCat=117">
                Electrical Engineering
            </a>
<br/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="jobDesc">
<p><strong><u>MCNEESE STATE UNIVERSITY</u></strong><strong> invites applicants for the position of Assistant Professor of
Engineering.</strong></p> <p><strong>DEPARTMENT: </strong>Engineering and Computer Science </p> <p><strong>POSITION INFORMATION:
</strong>This is a full-time, 9-month, unclassified, tenure-track position. The appointment begins in January 2023.</p> <p><strong>POSITION
NUMBER: </strong>F99507</p> <p><strong>SALARY: </strong>$76,000</p> <p><strong>REPORTING AUTHORITY: </strong>Department Head of Engineering
and Computer Science</p> <p><strong>POSITION DUTIES/RESPONSIBILITIES: </strong>The Assistant Professor of Engineering is responsible for
functions related to teaching courses, advising students, and conducting research. The assistant professor will work closely with faculty
and staff in the Department of Engineering and Computer Science.</p> <p><strong>REQUIRED/PREFERRED QUALIFICATIONS: </strong></p>
<p><u>Required</u>: </p> <ul>
<li>Master of Engineering with 18 hours in Electrical Engineering</li>
<li>Experience with Power
Engineering</li>
</ul> <p><u>Preferred</u>:</p> <ul>
<li>PhD in Electrical Engineering</li>
</ul> <p><strong>DEADLINE: </strong>Position
will remain open until filled.   
```
````

My code:

```
'salary': soup.select_one('strong:-soup-contains("Salary:")').get_text(strip=True)
```

Present solution:

```
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.
```

Expected solution:

```
'salary':$76,000.00 USD Per Year
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which allows you to programmatically access that job's info:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
html = '''
<script type="application/ld+json">
                    {
                        "@context"              :   "http://schema.org/",
                        "@type"                 :   "JobPosting",
                        "industry"              :   ["Academic/Education","Education"],
                        "title"                 :   "Assistant Professor of Engineering F99507",
                        "description"           :   "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&lt;u&gt;MCNEESE STATE UNIVERSITY&lt;/u&gt;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;strong&gt; invites applicants for the position of Assistant Professor of Engineering.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DEPARTMENT: &lt;/strong&gt;Engineering and Computer Science&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;POSITION INFORMATION: &lt;/strong&gt;This is a full-time, 9-month, unclassified, tenure-track position. The appointment begins in January 2023.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;POSITION NUMBER: &lt;/strong&gt;F99507&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;SALARY: &lt;/strong&gt;$76,000&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;REPORTING AUTHORITY: &lt;/strong&gt;Department Head of Engineering and Computer Science&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;POSITION DUTIES/RESPONSIBILITIES: &lt;/strong&gt;The Assistant Professor of Engineering is responsible for functions related to teaching courses, advising students, and conducting research. The assistant professor will work closely with faculty and staff in the Department of Engineering and Computer Science.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;REQUIRED/PREFERRED QUALIFICATIONS: &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;Required&lt;/u&gt;:&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Master of Engineering with 18 hours in Electrical Engineering&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Experience with Power Engineering&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;u&gt;Preferred&lt;/u&gt;:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;PhD in Electrical Engineering&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;DEADLINE: &lt;/strong&gt;Position will remain open until filled.&amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;APPLICATION PROCESS AND MATERIALS: &lt;/strong&gt;For the application process, applicants are required and &lt;strong&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;MUST&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; complete an electronic application and upload required documents listed below:&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Letter of Application (Cover Letter)&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Resume/Vitae&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Three Professional References (include: name, phone number, and e-mail address)&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Unofficial Transcripts&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;TO APPLY FOR THIS VACANCY, &lt;/strong&gt;click on the &lt;strong&gt;&amp;ldquo;APPLY&amp;rdquo;&lt;/strong&gt; button at the top of advertisement to complete the electronic application, which can be used for this vacancy as well as future job opportunities. Applicants are responsible for checking the status of their application to determine where they are in the recruitment process. Further status message information is located under the Information section of the Current Job Opportunities page.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;ALL JOB OFFERS ARE CONTINGENT UPON THE SUCCESSFUL RESULT OF A CRIMINAL BACKGROUND CHECK AND RECEIPT OF TRANSCRIPT(S) IF APPLICABLE.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;If you have questions regarding this recruitment, please contact the HR Liaison:&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;Kim Dronett at &lt;a rel=&quot;noopener&quot; href=&quot;kdronett@mcneese.edu&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;&gt;kdronett@mcneese.edu&lt;/a&gt; or (337) 475-5413.&lt;/p&gt;",
                        "datePosted"            :   "2022-09-02 09:48:23.527",

                    
                    
                        "validThrough"          :   "2023-03-01 23:59:59.9",
                    
                        "baseSalary"            :   {
                                                    "@type"         :   "MonetaryAmount",
                                                    "currency"      :   "USD",
                                                    "value"         :   {
                                                                                "@type"     :   "QuantitativeValue",
                                                                            
                                                                                "value" :   "76,000.00",
                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                "unitText"  :   "YEAR"
                                                                            }
                                                    },
                                
                        "hiringOrganization"    :   {
                                                        "@type"     :   "Organization",
                                                        
                                                            "id"        :   "http://www.mcneese.edu",
                                                            "url"       :   "http://www.mcneese.edu",
                                                                                                            
                                                        "name"      :   "McNeese State University"
                                                    },
                        "jobLocation"           :   {
                                                        "@type"     :   "Place",
                                                        "address"   :   {
                                                                            "@type"             :   "PostalAddress",
                                                                            "addressLocality"   :   "Lake Charles",
                                                                            "addressRegion"     :   "LA",
                                                                            "addressCountry"    :   "US"
                                                                        }
                                                    },
                    

                        "employmentType"        :   "FULL_TIME",
                        "image"                 :   "https://www.higheredjobs.com/assets/hej/img/HEJ_Logo_2c.png"
                    }
                </script>
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
                @media (min-width: 768px) { /*menus work different at XS*/
                    HEADER ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > .arrow,
                    HEADER ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
                        display: block;
                    }
                }
            </style>
</noscript>

<div class="col-6">
<h5>Resources</h5>
<ul>
<li><a href="/career/">Career Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="/salary/">Salary Data</a></li>
<li><a href="/career/resumes.cfm">Job Search Tips</a></li>
<li><a href="/career/ResumeService.cfm">Resume/CV Writing<br/> Service</a></li>
<li><a href="/articles/DiversityResources.cfm">Diversity Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="/career/SiteListings.cfm">Search Firms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="nav-item dropdown js-emplogin">
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/employers/">


<div class="" id="jobAttrib">
<div class="job-info">
<strong>Type:</strong>
        Full-Time
        <br/>
<strong>Salary:</strong>
            $76,000.00 USD Per Year
            <br/>
<strong>Posted:</strong>
            09/02/2022 
            <br/>
<strong>Application Due:</strong>
            Open Until Filled
            <br/>
<strong>Category:</strong>
<a class="job-cat" href="/faculty/search.cfm?JobCat=117">
                Electrical Engineering
            </a>
<br/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="jobDesc">
<p><strong><u>MCNEESE STATE UNIVERSITY</u></strong><strong> invites applicants for the position of Assistant Professor of
Engineering.</strong></p> <p><strong>DEPARTMENT: </strong>Engineering and Computer Science </p> <p><strong>POSITION INFORMATION:
</strong>This is a full-time, 9-month, unclassified, tenure-track position. The appointment begins in January 2023.</p> <p><strong>POSITION
NUMBER: </strong>F99507</p> <p><strong>SALARY: </strong>$76,000</p> <p><strong>REPORTING AUTHORITY: </strong>Department Head of Engineering
and Computer Science</p> <p><strong>POSITION DUTIES/RESPONSIBILITIES: </strong>The Assistant Professor of Engineering is responsible for
functions related to teaching courses, advising students, and conducting research. The assistant professor will work closely with faculty
and staff in the Department of Engineering and Computer Science.</p> <p><strong>REQUIRED/PREFERRED QUALIFICATIONS: </strong></p>
<p><u>Required</u>: </p> <ul>
<li>Master of Engineering with 18 hours in Electrical Engineering</li>
<li>Experience with Power
Engineering</li>
</ul> <p><u>Preferred</u>:</p> <ul>
<li>PhD in Electrical Engineering</li>
</ul> <p><strong>DEADLINE: </strong>Position
will remain open until filled.   
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
script = soup.select_one('script[type="application/ld+json"]')
# print(script.contents[0])
json_obj = json.loads(script.contents[0], strict=False)
print(json_obj['industry'])
print(json_obj['baseSalary']['value']['value'])
#### and here is a solution to find salary in actual html, not in script tag ###
salary_parent_div = soup.select_one('div.job-info')
salary = salary_parent_div.find('strong', string='Salary:').next_sibling
print(salary.strip())
```

This will print in terminal:

```
['Academic/Education', 'Education']
76,000.00
$76,000.00 USD Per Year
```

Of course you can drill down into that json object, and select more details about the job.
BeautifulSoup docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: some of the pages does not have salary, throwing error. I have used `if` statement. But I am getting syntax error. So, I am checking if the result is not empty and then only I will assign salary. `'salary': [if soup.select_one('div.job-info').find('strong',string='Salary:').next_sibling.strip(): soup.select_one('div.job-info').find('strong',string='Salary:').next_sibling.strip()]`

Comment: Yes @Mainland that is one way. I myself would prefer to get the data from the script tag.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus about your comment below my solution. In the world of programming it is common situation that a problem can be solved in several ways. When person is asking about Selenium solution I will try giving such. Not the other approach you maybe is more familiar with, but the way the topic starter asked about. You can add a note, that this problem can also be resolved in additional, more effective way and add that solution as well - as for me this will be the best way to do that.

Comment: Also you can assume that not all the people know all the possible software tools and approaches, it's OK. You are welcome to add the alternative approach with some explanations; how it works, why it is better. Maybe this way we, including me :) , will learn something new. I would more than appreciate this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes! I tried the tag approach. I found an interesting problem. For tag approach there two identical lines in the html, that is, `<script type="application/ld+json">`. Please, refer the html text in my question. You will see two lines that have same `<script type="application/ld+json">`.. How do a select the specific one? because salary element is in the second one.

Comment: @Mainland you can do `script = soup.select('script[type="application/ld+json"]')[1]` to select the second script.